# My character won't go down. Flappy Bird Clone

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

My character won't go downwards. I don't know what to do. My Character will only do up and not down. I've tried many things but I can't seem to figure out what to do. I'm new to Python so if this is something obvious, then sorry.

```
import pygame

black = pygame.Color("#000000")
white = pygame.Color("#FFFFFF")
blue = pygame.Color("#7ec0ee")

pygame.init()

size = 1024,768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird v.1b")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def ball(x,y):
  pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,[x,y], 20)

def gameover():
  text = render("Game Over!", True, black)
  screen.blit(text, [150, 250])


x = 350
y = 250
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
ground = 480

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          y_speed = -10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
          if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_speed = 5

      screen.fill(blue)
      ball(x,y)

      y += y_speed

      if  y > ground:
        gameover()
        y_speed = 0

      pygame.display.flip()
      clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Look at your `pygame.KEYDOWN` check - it has `pygame.K_UP` as its `event.key` check...

Comment: @Jon that appears intentional.

Comment: Doesn't work, I've already tried that. Do you think it may have something to do with my computer? It seems to work for my friend who has a similar code.

Comment: @sam-pyt yeah... sorry... tired eyes... thanks for the nudge

Comment: this seems to be some type of indentation problem. I put this in a file and fixed the indentation and it works as expected. ah yes, see your check for `pygame.KEYUP` events is nested inside the conditional for `pygame.KEYDOWN`.

Comment: I made both pygame.KEYDOWN & KEYUP set to K_DOWN and the character still goes only up.

Comment: UP arrow and DOWN arrow do the same thing. I've tried changing the values and I've re-written the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @sam-pyt said, it seems to be an indentation problem. I fixed the spacing inconsistencies and it worked on my end. The following is the code that worked for me.

```
import pygame

black = pygame.Color("#000000")
white = pygame.Color("#FFFFFF")
blue = pygame.Color("#7ec0ee")

pygame.init()

size = 1024,768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird v.1b")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def ball(x,y):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,[x,y], 20)

def gameover():
    text = render("Game Over!", True, black)
    screen.blit(text, [150, 250])


x = 350
y = 250
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
ground = 480

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = 5

    screen.fill(blue)
    ball(x,y)

    y += y_speed

    if  y > ground:
        gameover()
        y_speed = 0

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```